# How do I fix typos and errors in formulas? Stack Exchange seems to have a 6 character minimum edit limit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

The typo is 1-2 characters. Does Stack Exchange want broken formulas and typos?

What's the rationale for this limit?

(Maybe it's per setup. My current problem is with ham.stackexchange.com.)

Comment: Note: I did click "that solved my problem" but it really really didn't. It's the same question, but the answer is BS.

Comment: Do you have a specific example (I don't think the meta effect will be invoked in this case)?

Comment: I could not add the missing parenthesis to https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/11669/revisions. I added a proposed edit of adding it and "(extra characters, please remove)" which caused another user with more points who presumably has better edit rights to do only that 1-char edit as edit 3 in that link